# SEF url to normal url in Joomla

Tags: php, url, joomla, sef

In Joomla, suppose we have sef url like:

> http://www.mauriestate.com/en/mauritius-real-estate-community/groups/viewgroup/1-social-media-in-action.html

Now I have to append a variable "id" to this url, so i have done this:

```
$invite_url="http://www.mauriestate.com/en/mauritius-real-estate-community/groups/viewgroup/1-social-media-in-action.html"
$inv_url=$invite_url."&id="."123"
```

Now when i open `$inv_url` in browser, I am getting a 404 error.
Can you give me any idea how to append a variable to sef urls in php,
or
can you tell me the way to generate a normal url from  a sef url.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `&` with `?`:

```
$inv_url=$invite_url."?id="."123"
```

Comment: This is correct - you use `&` to separate GET parameters. You use `?` at the start of the GET parameters to indicate the end of the request path.